# Repeat in an if block?

Tags: applescript, repeat

I am trying to make a program that requires the person to select a file and am trying to confirm it. I ran into an issue when I tried to add a repeat in the if block. Is there any workaround for this because this is incredibly frustrating. Thanks in advance! :)

```
display dialog "Select the program"

tell application "Finder"

set filePath to POSIX path of (choose file)

end tell

display dialog "Are you sure this is the program that you have selected?" 

buttons {"Yes", "No"}

if the button returned is "No" then

end repeat

else
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though this may lead to my death, I'll answer. Study this:

```
set correctChoice to false

repeat until correctChoice is true -- "is true" is actually unnecessary

    --I took this next line out because it's unnecessary - you can put this text in the prompt of the choose file, below
    -- display dialog "Select the program"

    -- this doesn't need to be (and shouldn't be) in a Finder tell block, so I took that out, too:
    set filePath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Select the program")
    set myQuery to display dialog "Are you sure this is the program that you have selected?" buttons {"Yes", "No"}

    if the button returned of myQuery is "No" then
        --there is no repeat loop! Where do you want it? I assume you want the repeat outside of this process
        --end repeat
    else
        set correctChoice to true
    end if
end repeat
--maybe do other stuff
```

Doing what I assume you were attempting means putting the whole thing inside a repeat loop, which stops when a boolean variable is set to true. The if/then either keeps the original false value of the boolean, or sets it to true, thus allowing us to leave the repeat loop.
A "workaround" is a term for something needed to work within limitation or bug in language. You didn't need a workaround - you need to get your code right. Start simple (!!) and learn how various blocks work before you try to force the code to do what you think it should do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have the code all working now and it makes complete sense what I did wrong. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: You're welcome. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers : "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."